# Issue using RSpec to pass parameters to mocked model method in Rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mocking, rspec-rails

I'm trying to mock a user models save method to return false, and simulate what the controller would do in case of validation failure.

My spec looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  describe 'POST create_email_user' do
    it 'responds with errors json if saving the model fails' do
      @params = {
        :last_name => 'jones',
        :email => 'asdfasdfasfd@'
      }
      User.stub(:new_email_user) .with(@params) .and_return(@mock_user)

      @mock_user.stub(:save) .and_return(false)

      post :create_email_user, :user => @params, :format => :json

      response.body.should == @mock_user.errors.as_json
      response.status.should == :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Controller action looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create_email_user
    @user = User.new_email_user(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # code left out for demo purposes
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

When running this spec, I get the error that basically says the expected call to new_email_user got the wrong arguments:

```
  1) UsersController POST create_email_user responds with errors json if saving the model fails
     Failure/Error: post :create_email_user, :user => @params, :format => :json
       <User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, uid: string, provider: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, registration_id: integer, gender: string, authentication_token: string) (class)> received :new_email_user with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:last_name=>"jones", :email=>"asdfasdfasfd@"})
              got: (["last_name", "jones"], ["email", "asdfasdfasfd@"])
        Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

It seems like rails converts the has to an array of key value pairs, while my code is just using the straight hash in the setup.

How can I simulate this converting to an array, or am I doing else wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Drop the `.with` stub on user, since it isn't really relevant to the test and it is causing problems.

Without the `.with` the stub will return that value for any arguments.
So:

```
User.stub(:new_email_user).and_return(@mock_user)
```

I would then have a separate spec which ensures that:

`User.should_receive(:new_email_user).with(@params)`

And diagnose that problem in its own, narrow spec.